# Experiences with Continuous Integration tools

Tags: continuous-integration

We are trying to setup continuous integration. Our software suite consists of some 20 C# solutions. For some of the projects, unit tests (NUnit) are already available. We want to automize the build and test process, and get information on breaking changes early.

Recently, I tried to do so with Hudson. Some problems could be solved after intensive search thru the web, and some trial and error.

Now a bug prevents us from getting ahead: our solutions share some components, of course. When a shared component was changed, we do not want the build process to stop after the first failure - we want to know all of the projects which were broken. This cannot be handled by Hudson, also when using the "parameterized trigger plugin version 2.4" (it coped with starting the next project after the first completed perfectly, and failed after a build failed. Then, even the email notification was not sent, and afterwards, no downstream project is started at all - even in case of a succesful upstream project!).

With the quite disappointing experience with Hudson upto now, we think of taking a different system.

Can you recommend from your positive experiences a Continuous Integration tool which does:

- integrate with Subversion (both for getting source code and for triggering builds)
- start msbuild (e.g. Windows command line)
- trigger further projects, regardless of failures in upstream projects (must do!)
- notify by email when a build failed
- start unit tests with NUnit (e.g. command line)
- notify by email when a unit test failed
- co-operate with other computers in the build/test enviroment to deploy/test on other systems
- community support is available

Update:
I tried Jenkins. It does trigger further builds regardless of failures in upstream projects. Haven't tested the last two points yet.

Comment: I don't know how helpful this might be, but most of the companies I know that do .net, use [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) for doing CI. Obviously, you'll need to configure it to suit your neeeds, as with any other build server.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer: response from someone who works for a CI tool maker]

Bernhard, you're requirements (especially managing the inter-solution depenedencies) are a pretty good fit for my company's [AnthillPro](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/anthillpro).

- integrate with Subversion (both for getting source code and for
  triggering builds)

  - Yep. We'd use either polling or a SVN post-commit trigger to detect source code changes and immediately trigger a build.
- start msbuild (e.g. Windows command line)

  - We have an MS Build build type out of the box.
- trigger further projects, regardless of failures in upstream projects
  (must do!)

  - The triggering in AnthillPro is awesome. It can handle large build graphs, building any dependent components in parallel while not doing unnecessary builds. We've been improving this capability since we first introduced triggering in 2001.
- notify by email when a build failed

  - Email and/or instance message.
- start unit tests with NUnit (e.g. command line)

  - NUnit test result parsing is supported.
- notify by email when a unit test failed

  - Similar to notification of build failure
- co-operate with other computers in the build/test enviroment
  to deploy/test on other systems

  - Fully supports deployments of builds through environments. Environments are a first oder concept within AnthillPro.
- community support is available

  - Here's the possible issue. Our product isn't free. It's the gold-plated CI/CD tool.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Eric. Beyond investing some time, I do not have a budget for CI...

Comment: I thought that might be the case, hence the warning. Always delicate to say, "check out my tool" when it might be appropriate without being a spamming jerk.